# print multiple HTML(dynamic) on button click using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

I have created application which prints customer invoice. I want to print all invoice between two invoice No. like print all invoice between Invoice No. 10 to Invoice No. 30.

I want to print them all in single click or single popup or without any popup.

This code generating multiple popup

Here is my code

```
   $("#btnPrint").click(function () {

                var invStartNo = 10;
                var invUptoNo = 30;
                for (var i = invStartNo; i < invUptoNo; i++) {


                    var contents = functionWhichReturnHTML_byInvNo(i);//this function return dynamically html by invoice no

                    var frame1 = $('<iframe />');
                    frame1[0].name = "frame1";
                    frame1.css({ "position": "absolute", "top": "-1000000px" });
                    $("body").append(frame1);
                    var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;
                    frameDoc.document.open();
                    //Create a new HTML document.
                    frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>Account Statement</title>');
                    frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
                    //Append the external CSS file.

                    frameDoc.document.write('<link href="../../Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />');


                    //Append the DIV contents.
                    frameDoc.document.write(contents);
                    frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
                    frameDoc.document.close();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        window.frames["frame1"].focus();
                        window.frames["frame1"].print();
                        frame1.remove();
                    }, 1000);


                }
            });
```

Comment: What is the issue which you are currently facing?

Comment: Create 20 frames inside frame1?

Comment: its generating multiple popup i want to print all invoice with single popup (or without popup if possible)

Comment: how to create 20 frames inside frame1. Please could you send some sample code @jeroen Heier

Answer (score 0):

```
           var invStartNo = 10;
            var invUptoNo = 30;
     for (var i = invStartNo; i < invUptoNo; i++) {

   var contents = functionWhichReturnHTML_byInvNo(i);//this function return dynamically html by invoice no(call synchronously)

                //Append the DIV contents.
                frameDoc.document.write(contents);

      }
```